# Sending Message to Multiple Numbers using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i have a list of numbers.

```
ArrayList<String> numbers;
```

I want to sent message to all these number using Intent, together .
I did this with email like sending email to multiple people , How to do for message ?

```
public static void send(Context ctx, String[] addy, String subject,
        String body,File attachment) {
    try {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER,
                addy);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        //sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(attachment));
        ctx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                "Send via which Application?"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "No activity was found to handle this action",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is opening the message app but the numbers stored in addy are not listed in message sent to column

Answer (score 1):

> I did this with email like sending email to multiple people

Assuming that you used a third-party application via an `Intent` action, whether this works is up to the author of the third-party application. You have no way of knowing whether each of the hundreds of email apps for Android support specifying multiple addresses, unless you test them all.

> How to do for message ?

You send them one at a time.

Your code is dreadful, using an undocumented MIME type that will not necessarily be honored on all devices, but `EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER` is supposed to be a `String`, not a `String[]`.

`ACTION_SEND`, or `ACTION_SENDTO` with an `smsto:` address, similarly is only guaranteed to support a single number and will give you the same problems as you have with sending email that way.

`SmsManager` has methods for directly sending SMS; they too only support one phone number at a time.

Comment: Thanks , however when we use default message application we have an option of selecting contacts from  contacts apps. How that is done . There we can select multiple contacts and send message together .

Comment: @SureshBora: First, there is no "default message application". There are dozens of "default message applications", as device manufacturers can and do replace the open source "message application" with their own. I do not see where in the open source messaging app you can select contacts at all, let alone multiple contacts. Nor do I see where in the open source contacts app where you can select multiple contacts and send a message "together".

Comment: @SureshBora: If you are seeing this in some manufacturer's version of the messaging and/or contacts apps, please contact the manufacturer for details. However, as I already stated in my answer, you cannot assume that just because *one* messaging app from *one* manufacturer supports this that *all* messaging apps from *all* manufacturers and third-party authors support this.

Answer (score 1):

for java developer use

```
public static void send(Context ctx, String[] address, String subject,
                        String body, File attachment) {

    List<String> mylist = Arrays.asList(address);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(";", "smsto:", "");
    mylist.forEach(sj::add);
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse(sj.toString()));

    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(ctx.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        ctx.startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

for those using kotlin, use

```
fun send(ctx: Context, address: Array<String>, subject: String, body: String, attachment: File) {

    val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

    val data = address.toList().joinToString(";", "smsto:")

    sendIntent.data = Uri.parse(data)
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body)

    if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(ctx.packageManager) != null) {
        ctx.startActivity(sendIntent)
    }
}
```